# How to custom CALayer using subclassing

Tags: iphone, calayer, quartz-graphics, cashapelayer

On UIView there are number of CALayers. Each CALayer consists of CAShapeLayers. CAShapeLayers' path property consists of UIBezierPath.

My objective is when i tap on CALayer i want to get points which i used in the drawing of UIBezierPath. For that i thought of subclassing CALayer which has NSMutableArray to store points. I will be saving points when i am drawing in particular CALayer. So whenever i tap on particular CALayer i will get points associated to that. Also i want to give tag to each CALayer. I do not know how to do this.

The second way is to use CALayer's inbuilt property which will give me points captured in CALayer. But i am not aware of this kind of property.

Please share your ideas how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the UIView that contains the CALayer to handle the touch events, there is no built in Touch events for CALayers. `- (CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint` returns the "deepest" CALayer that the point from the touch event is within. So, if you call `[self.layer hitTest:point]` it will check all your sublayers and return the correct `CALayer`

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CALayerSubclass *taplayer = [self.layer hitTest:point]
    NSArray *points = [taplayer getPoints];
}
```

There is no way to get out of a CGPath the points you fed into it. The best you can do are [these methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000959-CH1g-439779) about getting info from the path. So, like you said, your best bet is to subclass CALayer and put all the info you need in a data structure to retrieve later.

```
// .h
@interface CALayerSubclass : CALayer

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *points;

@end

// .m
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    ...
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:point1 controlPoint2:point2];
    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point1]];  
    [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point2]];  
    ...
}
```

Just store all the CGPoints (or most other Core Graphics structure) in an NSValue and throw it into an array.

Comment: I actually want to retrieve all the points from CALayer which contains path drawing. How to do that?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. Misread your question. Hope my edits help.

Comment: Note that -drawInContext: does not get called in CAShapeLayer.

Comment: Care to elaborate? It isn't explicitly called but if used properly, it would be after calling 'setNeedsDisplay' on a CALayerSubclass object.

Comment: @ProudMember -drawInContext does get called in CAShapeLayer if you set its frame size (width/height) to non zero values